# my app doesn't stop running when i close vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, process, localhost, task, port

I work part time while i code in my free time specifically mern stack. Since i work using my laptop, i basically just stop coding, open outlook and get to work instead of actually stopping the app from running in the console. And then after a while i would just close vscode while the app is still running. Well, I have obviously been doing this unconsciously, im pretty sure every programmer has closed vscode while their app was still running at a point, But just recently, i noticed the app kept running even after closing vscode. By that i mean that vscode would not be open at all but i can go to localhost:3000 and my app would be working fine. i dont understand why. and then when i open vscode again and i try to run my backend to localhost:5000 it gives me this error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1740:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1788:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1876:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\gerar\Programming\typescript\doctor-appointment-application\backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
    at C:\Users\gerar\Programming\typescript\doctor-appointment-application\backend\app.ts:45:9
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\gerar\Programming\typescript\doctor-appointment-application\backend\app.ts:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5000
}
```

Obviously meaning that localhost:5000 is currently in use and my app is still running, meanwhile since the console is obviously cleared from closing vscode in the first place, i have no way of stopping it myself using ctrl + c. Is there a way of using vscode to stop what was running on the localhost before? or is there anything you recommend to stop it from happening again? I already tried to kill the process using task manager and cmd but i couldnt find it. i could restart my laptop to fix the problem but i obviously dont want to do that everytime i encounter this issue.

Comment: `taskkill` is a thing.